# Dynamically Adding Content to Text Fields Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

So here is my problem. I have the below set of javascript code and HTML.

What is supposed to happen is that as you click on various checkboxes in a form, the script is supposed to take the Value of the Checkbox you checked and fill in a text field below that has a similar "name" identifier. The below code works for all values but one. The one with a space in the value "Character Only" doesn't work. I tried to use the Javascript method `.Replace(" ", "-")` to accomplish replacing the space with a hyphen but it doesn't seem to work. Since the HTML is being dynamically created via a PHP loop, I can't just add in the needed values and hard code everything.

Is there a way to make

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/retched/4rpVa/)** - The full program and HTML layout.

**The Javascript (Click the JSFiddle link to see the entire result)**

```
function autofill(ElementName) {
     //window.alert('You got this: ' + ElementName);

    if(document.getElementById('keyword-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('keyword-entry-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value = document.getElementById('keyword-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value;
    } else {
    document.getElementById('keyword-entry-' + ElementName.toLowerCase()).value = '';
    }
}
 // window.alert('This value is: ' + document.getElementById('keyword-ally').value.toLowerCase() );

//--> </script>
```

**The PHP being used to create the HTML elements for the above JScript**

```
<?php 
$keywords = array("Ally" , "Breaker" , "Character Only" , "Combo" , "Desperation" , "Item" , "Kick" , "Multiple" , "Powerful" , "Punch" , "Ranged" , "Reversal" , "Stance" , "Stun" , "Taunt" , "Terrain" , "Throw" , "Unique" , "Weapon");
$i =0;
foreach($keywords as $keyword_name) {

echo '<td style="width: 20%;">' . zen_draw_checkbox_field('ufs_keywords[]', $keyword_name, in_array($keyword_name, $pInfo->resources), '', 'id="keyword-' . str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($keyword_name)) . '"') . ' <label for="keyword-' . str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($keyword_name)) .'">' . $keyword_name . "</label><br />" . zen_draw_input_field('ufs_keywords_entry[]', '', 'id="keyword-entry-' . str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($keyword_name)) . '" style="width:100px; float: right;"') . "</td>" . "\n\n";
$i++;
echo ($i % 5 == 0 ? "</tr>\n\n<tr>" : "");
}

?>
```

Comment: In the fiddle the text box has id keyword-entry-character_only
while the check box has id keyword-entry-character-only.

Comment: Updated the fiddle but its the same result.

Comment: That's probably because replace isn't there. http://jsfiddle.net/4rpVa/2/

Comment: I had it up there in my local file but took it out when it also wasn't work. Oddly enough it was that SAME line you used.